# Check if line in richtextbox contains numbers

Tags: vb.net, regex

I have a list of strings in my richtextbox. I need a code to check if there are numbers in the first line, if there is then proceed with the rest of my code, else delete first line.

Answer (score 3):

Has a number: \d

Has only numbers: ^\d+$

Answer (score 0):

Replace "asda2323" with your line.

```
Dim x() As Char = "asda2323".ToCharArray
For Each y As Char In x
  If Char.IsNumber(y) Then
    'Delete my line
  End If
Next
```